# Cannot install latest version of GnuPG from source

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, gnupg

I tried installing the latest GnuPG from the source tar.gz package but I am encountering these errors.

Need help to fix these problem. I Downloaded the packages mentioned in error message but still I can't install or build it successfully.

I attached a screenshot of the errors.

[image: screenshot of the compiler errors]

Comment: @edwinksl Have you checked the post source?

Comment: "*Can't install them also*" you can't because of...?

Comment: __Close Voters__ Do would you comment how is this unclear question?

Comment: I answered your question. Have you checked it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ubuntu Xenial installs GnuPG 2.1.11, which is available as `gpg2` binary. There is a `gpg` which is from version 1.14. The latest version is 2.1.15. You need to install it from source by compiling if you wanted that version.

To compile from source, you need to first get the updated libraries of these packages -

```
npth         (ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/npth/)
libgpg-error (ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/libgpg-error/)
libgcrypt    (ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/libgcrypt/)
libksba      (ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/libksba/)
libassuan    (ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/libassuan/)
```

**1. Installing `npth`**

1. Download the version 1.2 of `npth`

   ```
   wget ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/npth/npth-1.2.tar.bz2
   ```
2. Unpack

   ```
   tar xf npth-1.2.tar.bz2
   ```
3. Go to it's dir and build it

   ```
   cd npth-1.2  
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

**2. Install `libgpg-error`**

1. Download the version 1.24

   ```
   wget https://www.gnupg.org/ftp/gcrypt/libgpg-error/libgpg-error-1.24.tar.bz2
   ```
2. Unpack, `cd` to the directory, configure, make & install

   ```
   tar xf libgpg-error-1.24.tar.bz2
   cd libgpg-error-1.24
   ./configure
   make
   make check
   sudo make install
   ```

**3. Install `libgcrypt`**

1. Download the version 1.7.3

   ```
   wget https://www.gnupg.org/ftp/gcrypt/libgcrypt/libgcrypt-1.7.3.tar.bz2
   ```
2. Unpack, `cd` to the directory, configure, make & install

   ```
   tar xf libgcrypt-1.7.3.tar.bz2
   cd libgcrypt-1.7.3
   ./configure
   make
   make check
   sudo make install
   ```

**4. Install `libassuan`**

1. Download the version 2.3.4

   ```
   wget https://www.gnupg.org/ftp/gcrypt/libassuan/libassuan-2.4.3.tar.bz2
   ```
2. Unpack, `cd` to the directory, configure, make & install

   ```
   tar xf libassuan-2.4.3.tar.bz2
   cd libassuan-2.4.3
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

**5. Install `libksba`**

1. Download the version 1.3.4

   ```
   wget https://www.gnupg.org/ftp/gcrypt/libksba/libksba-1.3.4.tar.bz2
   ```
2. Unpack, `cd` to the directory, configure, make & install

   ```
   tar xf libksba-1.3.4.tar.bz2        
   cd libksba-1.3.4
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

**6. Now Install `gnupg2`**

1. Download version 2.1.15

   ```
   wget https://www.gnupg.org/ftp/gcrypt/gnupg/gnupg-2.1.15.tar.bz2
   ```
2. Unpack, `cd`, configure

   ```
   tar xf gnupg-2.1.15.tar.bz2        
   cd gnupg-2.1.15
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

After installation, you should is complete, check the version. But before that use this command to so that newly installed libraries can be loaded.

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Then to check version

```
gpg2 --version
```

You can also check where it is installed with

```
which gpg2
```

It should return

```
/usr/local/bin/gpg2
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: running this today I had to update libgpg-error to 1.29 and libassuan to 2.5.3

Comment: I installed version `1.6.0`: https://github.com/Tazovsky/gpgme-1.6.0-rhel7.9/blob/master/Dockerfile, but system is when I run `gpg --version` I see old `1.3.2`. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Open a Terminal window ant type:

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install gpa
```

gpa is a graphical interface for gpg and it will install gpg automatically.

Comment: It will install gpg, but that will not be the latest version